# Domino diamonds

Tags: mathematics

You have a large collection of dominos, each labeled with two distinct symbols drawn from some infinite alphabet.  The symbols have 180-degree rotational symmetry so dominoes can be rotated.  In other words, these two dominoes are equivalent:

```
       +---------+---------+             +---------+---------+
       |         |         |             |         |         |
       |    N    |    S    |      ~      |    S    |    N    |
       |         |         |             |         |         |
       +---------+---------+             +---------+---------+
```

You wish to arrange your entire collection into 4-domino diamonds of the form

```
           +---------+---------+
           |         |         |
           |    Z    |    S    |
           |         |         |
           +---------+---------+
+---------+---------+ +---------+---------+
|         |         | |         |         |
|    X    |    Z    | |    S    |    N    |
|         |         | |         |         |
+---------+---------+ +---------+---------+
           +---------+---------+
           |         |         |
           |    Z    |    S    |
           |         |         |
           +---------+---------+,
```

where X, Z, S, N are distinct symbols.  Actually, you have made lots of progress, having already assembled an infinite number of copies of each possible diamond.  And more good news: the number of remaining dominoes is finite and a multiple of four!

By disassembling at most a finite number of your existing diamonds, will you always be able to arrange your entire collection as desired?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I claim that

> yes, you can always arrange your collection this way.

The reason why:

> Given any domino, we can swap it out for one with one symbol changed: if you want to change `AB` to `AC`, find a diamond of the form:
>     `-YA-`
>     `XYAB`
>     `-YA-`
>  and replace the right-hand domino.
>
>  Now that you have this trick, it's easy to make any domino into any other domino: if one symbol is on your target domino, then swap out the other. If neither is, swap one, then swap the other.
>
>  So, using this process, you can transmute every set of 4 dominoes into any diamond you like. This requires at most two swaps per domino, and so there are a finite number of broken diamonds.